# Sharepoint security trimming and OneDrive for business

Tags: security, security-trimming, onedrive

If I have library with 2 folders, and John Smith have access to only one folder - would both be visible for him, if he connects this lib with OneDrive for Business? Does security trimming work in OneDrive too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security trimming works across SharePoint. As long as you don't have read access, you cannot see the content.

Comment: Hi Trevor! But what about if I connected SharePoint library with OneDrive for business?

Comment: Security is respected by the client.

Comment: I confused You. I mean "permissions" control, does it work if lib is shared in OneDrive, or not

Comment: Again, the OneDrive client respect permissions in SharePoint. OneDrive the service runs on top of SharePoint.